# Unable to pass values from Feeder file in a request

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

From a feeder file i am taking values called product id, product type and weight. I am using these Values to add items to basket, Based on product type add to basket request gets changes. I added if condition in the script to differentiate the add to basket request. I am also setting the productid and produt type values in session, While running the script i am getting errors and add to basket request is not working. can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Feeder file is in CSV format -

```
p_ProductId,p_maxWeightValue,p_productType
251627289,6.8,LooseQuantity
```

Below is the full function -

```
object addToBasket {
        var j: Int=0;
val AddToBasket_getProductAndQty=
    feed(f_AddtoBasket)
                .exec(session => {
                var p_ProductId=session("p_ProductId").as[String]
                var p_maxWeightValue=session("p_maxWeightValue").as[String]             
                val v_c_maxWeightValue=session("p_maxWeightValue").as[String]   
                var p_ProductType=session("p_ProductType").as[String]               
                //val v_c_ProductTypeValue=session("p_ProductTypeValue").as[String]                     
        session.set("c_ProductId",p_ProductId).set("c_ProductForSale","true").set("productfound","0").set("c_maxWeightValue",p_maxWeightValue).set("p_ProductType",p_ProductType)
  
        })   
      
    
                            

    .doIf("${c_ProductId.exists()}"){
        doIf(session => session("c_ProductForSale").as[String].equals("true")){

    doIfOrElse("${c_basketproducts.exists()}"){
        foreach("${c_basketproducts}","basketproductid"){               
        
        doIfEqualsOrElse("${basketproductid}","${c_ProductId}"){
            
            exec(session => {                                               
                val c_getbasketqty = session("c_productquantity").as[List[String]]
                var k = c_getbasketqty(j).toInt ;               
                var l = k + 1;
                session.set("newValue",l).set("oldValue",k).set("productfound","1")})                           
            }
            {
            doIf(session => session("productfound").as[Int] !=1){exec(session => {                                              
                
                session.set("newValue","1").set("oldValue","0")})}
            }
            .exec(session => {j+=1;session;})//println("increment value:"+j)
            
        }//foreach loop
    }
    {
        exec(session => {session.set("newValue","1").set("oldValue","0")})//println("value not set for newValue:")
    }   
    .exec(session => session.removeAll("productfound"))
    //set new basket with added items.
    .doIfOrElse("${c_basketproducts.exists()}"){exec(session => {
        var c_basketproducts = session("c_basketproducts").as[List[String]]
        var c_productquantity = session("c_productquantity").as[List[String]]
        c_basketproducts = c_basketproducts:+session("c_ProductId").as[String]
        c_productquantity = c_productquantity:+session("newValue").as[String]
        //println("Baset Products and Quantity:" +c_basketproducts +":"+c_productquantity)
        session.set("c_basketproducts",c_basketproducts).set("c_productquantity",c_productquantity)
    })}
    {
        exec(session => {  
            var c_basketproducts = List[String](session("c_ProductId").as[String])
            var c_productquantity = List[String](session("newValue").as[String])    
            //println("Baset Products and Quantity:" + c_basketproducts + ":"+c_productquantity)        
            session.set("c_basketproducts",c_basketproducts).set("c_productquantity",c_productquantity)
        })
    }
    
    .exec(session => {
        j=0;
        //println("Product added sku and quantity"+":"+session("c_ProductId").as[String] + ":" + session("newValue").as[String] +":"+ session("oldValue").as[String]);
        session})

    }}

val AddToBasket = exec(AddToBasket_getProductAndQty)
        .exec(session => {
            var v_c_ProductId=session("c_ProductId").as[String]
            var v_newValue=session("newValue").as[String]
            var v_oldValue=session("oldValue").as[String]
            val v_c_maxWeightValue=session("c_maxWeightValue").as[Float]
            val v_c_ProductType=session("p_ProductType").as[String]
            if((v_c_maxWeightValue > 0) && (v_c_ProductType == "CatchWeight")) {
                   var requestBodyAddToBasket="{\"items\":[{\"id\":\""+v_c_ProductId+"\",\"newValue\":"+v_newValue+",\"oldValue\":"+v_oldValue+",\"newUnitChoice\":\"pcs\",\"oldUnitChoice\":\"pcs\",\"catchWeight\":"+v_c_maxWeightValue+"}],\"loggedInAction\":\"update-trolley-item\"}"
                   println("Variation Product: Mohana")
                           session.set("requestBodyAddToBasket",requestBodyAddToBasket)            

                }else if ((v_c_maxWeightValue > 0) && (v_c_ProductType == "LooseQuantity")) {
                   var requestBodyAddToBasket="{\"items\":[{\"id\":\""+v_c_ProductId+"\",\"newValue\":"+v_newValue+",\"oldValue\":"+v_oldValue+",\"newUnitChoice\":\"kg\",\"oldUnitChoice\":\"kg\"}],\"loggedInAction\":\"update-trolley-item\"}"
                   println("Variation Product: Mohana")
                           session.set("requestBodyAddToBasket",requestBodyAddToBasket)            

                } 
                else{
                   var requestBodyAddToBasket="{\"items\":[{\"id\":\""+v_c_ProductId+"\",\"newValue\":"+v_newValue+",\"oldValue\":"+v_oldValue+",\"newUnitChoice\":\"pcs\",\"oldUnitChoice\":\"pcs\"}],\"loggedInAction\":\"update-trolley-item\"}"
            session.set("requestBodyAddToBasket",requestBodyAddToBasket)               
            }       

         })                         
        .doIf(session => session.contains("c_ProductId")){doIf(session => session("c_ProductForSale").as[String].equals("true")){doIf(session => session.contains("c_csrf1")){doIf(session => session("c_ProductForSale").as[String] == "true"){                            
            pause("${p_AddToBasket}").group("UK_AddToBasket"){group("${scriptid}_AddToBasket"){exec(http("Main_Request")
            .put("/groceries/en-GB/trolley/items?_method=PUT")                          
            .body(StringBody("${requestBodyAddToBasket}"))                              
            .header("x-csrf-token", "${c_csrf1}")
            .header("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest") 
            //.header("x-tesco-waiting", "false")          
            .header("Accept", "application/json")    
            .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")               
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")     
            .header("Origin", "https://www.tesco.com")     
            .check(status.in(200))                          
            .check(regex("successful\": true").find(0).exists,
            regex("""isAmendBasket\": true,""").find(0).optional.saveAs("v_amendMode"),
            regex("""message\": \"Success\"""").find(0).optional.saveAs("v_addtobasketstatus"),
            regex("""guidePrice\": 0""").find(0).optional.saveAs("c_guideprice"),
            regex("""guidePrice\": (.+?),""").find(0).optional.saveAs("c_guidepricevalue")                      
            
            ))}}
            }}}}
            .doIf("${v_addtobasketstatus.isUndefined()}"){exec(session => {
                println("Addto basket failed:" + session("scriptid").as[String] + ":" + session("p_SigninId").as[String] + ":" +session("c_ProductId").as[String])
                session.set("temp","temp")
                })}
                }
```

Error i am facing while running the script -

```
12:46:58.651 [ERROR] i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-31' crashed with 'j.u.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named 'p_ProductType' is defined', forwarding to the next one
12:46:58.657 [ERROR] i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-14' crashed with 'j.u.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named 'c_ProductId' is defined', forwarding to the next one
```

Comment: can you share the full function for the 'If condition I am using these values' part?

Comment: Full function is edited in the question, please can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

Below changes helped me to resolve the issue?

`var p_ProductType=session("p_ProductType").as[String]`
to

`var p_ProductType=session("p_productType").as[String]`

as per the name in feeder file. Post that my script worked as expected.